# Should I cast in my lambda or cast the IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, linq, casting

In my project I have a `MyClass` which implements `IMyClass`. I need to return a list of `IMyClass` by transforming a list of other items. For simplicity's sake, assume that I can create a `MyClass` just by passing another item into its constructor, i.e. `new MyClass(item)`.

Consider the following two lines, which (as far as I know) produce the same result:

```
var option1 = items.Select(item => new MyClass(item)).Cast<IMyClass>().ToList()
var option2 = items.Select(item => new MyClass(item) as IMyClass).ToList()
```

It seems to me that option #1 would require a double enumeration, once to cast all the items to my interface and once to generate the list. If I'm right then option #2 would be smarter. However, I've **never** seen any code using something like option #2, and I tend to assume that I'm not smart enough to come up with something clever that the rest of the C# community did not.

On a side note, I think option #2 is more aesthetically pleasing, but that's just me.

**My question is:** is my option #2 a better idea like I think it is? Are there are any gotchas I'm missing or other reasons why I'd want to stick with option #1? Or am I perhaps comparing two stupid ideas when there is a smarter third one that I'm missing completely?

Comment: Don't forget that enumerables are lazy and composable! Option 1 will not cause it to be enumerated twice...

Comment: Why do you need to cast if `MyClass` implements `IMyClass`?

Comment: You know you can always spell out the types without inference? That is, `var result = items.Select<SourceType, IMyClass>(x => new MyClass(x)).ToList();` This will return `IEnumerable<IMyClass>` :)

Comment: @DanielGabriel Because my method returns a `List<IMyClass>`. You cannot return a `List<MyClass>` in its place. See also: [covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx)

Comment: @ean5533 Change the signature to an IList<MyClass> instead?

Comment: @AlexanderR Not appropriate for my use case. I want my API to use interfaces, not classes.

Comment: @ean5533 Don't forget that 'myvar as Class' returns null if myvar cannot by cast to Class, while '.Cast<T>()' and '(Class)myvar' throw exceptions.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'd go for option 3:

```
var option3 = items.Select<Foo, IMyClass>(item => new MyClass(item))
                   .ToList()
```

Alternatively, don't use `as` but just cast normally:

```
var option4 = items.Select(item => (IMyClass) new MyClass(item))
                   .ToList()
```

Both of these seem cleaner than using `Cast`.

Oh, and as of C# 4 with .NET 4 (due to covariance), you could put a type argument on the `ToList` call instead:

```
var option5 = items.Select(item => new MyClass(item))
                   .ToList<IMyClass>()
```

Comment: Options 3 and 4 didn't do it for me aesthetically, but option 5 definitely does. Hooray for choice!

Comment: Shouldn't option 4 be `var option4 = items.Select(item => (**IMyClass**) new MyClass(item))`?

Answer (score 3):

> It seems to me that option #1 would require a double enumeration

This is not true. In both cases, the `items` collection is only enumerated when you get to `ToList()`.

The line

```
var option1 = items.Select(item => new MyClass(item)).Cast<IMyClass>().ToList()
```

is equivalent to

```
var option1 = items.Select(item => new MyClass(item)).Select(x => (IMyClass)x).ToList()
```

The only difference between the two is that the first one requires two function calls per item (unless C# inlines the lambdas somehow, which I don't believe is the case) while the second option requires only one.

Personally, I'd go with the second one as a matter of style.

Comment: +1. My personal reason to pick 2 - I don't like `Cast` in such context. It show that one was not able to decide what items to put in the collection. Note that in a lot of  cases if you don't need particular type of `List<T>` you can use `IEnumerable<MyClass>` in places where `IEnumerable<IMyClass>` required - so you may actually need cast in some cases making code easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Which one you use is a matter of preference, something we really cannot answer for you.

But your intuition if sort-of correct that `Cast` adds a second layer of iteration to your loop. It's very minor, and I doubt it will produce any measurable difference in performance, but the `Cast` method returns a new `IEnumerable` object that basically does this:

```
foreach (object obj in source) yield return (TResult)obj;
```

The effect is mostly another level on the call stack; since it uses `yield` it will only iterate on demand, like most other `IEnumerable` methods. But it will have to return though two levels of iterator state instead of one. Whether that matters for you is something you'll need to measure for your own applications.

(Also note that, at least according to the reference source, it does an unsafe cast, which *might* throw an exception if the cast is invalid. That's another reason to prefer your option #2.)

Answer (score 1):

You can always provide explicit type arguments to your Select

```
   var option2 = items.Select<IItem,IMyClass>(item => new MyClass(item)).ToList();
```

where IItem is a type or interface to which items could be cast.